# Error after changing Compile using Android version

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, xamarin.android

I in trying to make my first Xamarin.Android app in Visual Studio 2017.
It is necessary to use Android 7.1 (Nougat) or lower versions but default it's Android 8.1,
and when i try to change that, VS gets a lot of errors.

How i think, main error it's:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

What i already tried:

- Update Xamarin.Android.Support.Design in NuGet Package Manager to Latest version
- Change Target android version in "Android Manifest"
- Download android SDK platforms and tools in Android SKD Manager

**Please look at this pictures: 
[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wErAo.png) and
[Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc2xJ.png)**

Help me :)

Comment: You are changing your `Target Framework Version` which makes the default NuGet package incompatible. I would recommend reading the following documentation on this subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is to change a **Target android version** and not a Target Framework Version, thanks [Jon Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220705/error-after-changing-compile-using-android-version/51229554#comment89422830_51220705)